# No JaxWS Tutorial works : Java overcomplicated compared to ASP.NET

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, jax-ws

I have read a dozen tutorial on JaxWS and wsgen and none works ! Java really oever complicated for beginners compared to asp.net : in ASP.Net I can make a WS in 5 minutes not in Java : I'm stuck for several days now.

For example I followed this tutorial http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/jax-ws/create-and-consume-web-service-using-jax-ws/

I'm using Eclipse Luna, JDK 7 and Tomcat 7 and generated stubs and wsdl with wsgen.

I created this Endpoint Publisher class :

```
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;
import com.demo.JaxWS;

public class HelloEndpointPublisher {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/EclipseJaxWSutotorial/JaxWS", new JaxWS());

    }

}
```

When running it as Java Application why do I get this error and how to fix it ?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider: Provider com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl could not be instantiated
```

Update : I do not use maven. I have used wsgen by command line and it generated all classes, wsdl and xsd fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you check your library dependencies? Check if you have jaxws-rt in your library path. Basically you the maven dependencies will look like this

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I do not use maven. I have used wsgen by command line and it generated all classes, wsdl and xsd fine.

Comment: Based on the link you have followed, you don't need to run it on Tomcat. It's a standalone web service. All you need is to run the `HelloEndpointPublisher` as a Java Application and then open a browser and enter `http://localhost:8080/EclipseJaxWSutotorial/JaxWS?wsdl`. If you running this in a web container and would like to run it in Tomcat Server, you need to build a Web Project and add the code and check if the jaxws-rt is included in your `WEB-INF/lib` folder for application OR in `<tomcat_home>/lib` folder

Comment: The Java App is not compiling when I run it so I cannot point to http://localhost:8080/EclipseJaxWSutotorial/JaxWS?wsdl successfully